# How do I put latin text in a Cyrillic document?

Tags: text, cyrillic

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1,OT2]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Neki tekst na Srpskom (NAME)

\end{document}
```

I am writing a document that is in Cyrillic and I need to write an English name at some point. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do nothing special.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Цей текст українською мовою. Англійське ім'я John.

\end{document}
```

(Text courtesy of Google Translate.)

[image]

If you use the obsolete method of OT2,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT2,OT1]{fontenc}

% use Type1 fonts
\AtBeginDocument{\fontencoding{OT2}\selectfont}
\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{OT2}{cmr}{wncyr}
%%%

\newcommand{\latin}[1]{{\fontencoding{OT1}\selectfont#1}}

\begin{document}

Neki tekst na Srpskom (\latin{NAME})

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey so the thing is I am writing in Latin and it compiles as cyrillic.

Comment: @Nik Please, add an example of what you're doing to your question.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: @Nik And why are you using that obsolete method?

Comment: Because I am writing a bunch of math so it would be inconvenient to switch between Latin and Cyrillic keyboards that often.

Comment: @Nik I added a method.

Comment: thank you a lot!